# Migrate ASP.NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with React and Redux in VS Profession 2019 and use included SubProject Library with .NET Standard 2.1 in Solution.

After the release of .NET 5, I change via Project => Properties => Application:

- Library from .NET Standard 2.0 to .NET Standard 2.1
- ASP MVC Core from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5

The application works perfectly, but if I want to edit Controller, where I include a dependency to Libraries from other projects I see Interface with the red color name:
[image]

I am not sure where is the problem, and why VS does not find a reference to the libraries.

[image]

Because program works, I have added references, but only VS do not see this

Comment: Did you try .NET 5 in all your .NET Standard sub-projects ?

Comment: It only allows in .NET Library - Project => Properties => Application use in Target framework, use :NET Standard 2.1 or lower

Comment: As an aside, it’s actually a bit peculiar that your library worked in .NET Core 3.1, since .NET Core 3.1 necessitated .NET Standard 2.1, but it sounds like you were using .NET Standard 2.0 previously. You must have lucked out had not have made any calls that differed between versions. (.NET will try to interact with any .NET library, but will throw runtime exceptions if the expected interface differs from what it’s coded to.)

Comment: @JanSršeň: You can still migrate your .NET Standard libraries to .NET 5, assuming you don’t require backward compatibility with .NET Framework or .NET Core 3.x. You may need to modify your `*.csproj` files directly. Still, that ought not be necessary; a .NET 5 project can still reference a .NET Standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy Solution**

Change in each .NET Standard library *.csproj from:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

to:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

Update Nuget packages

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense sometimes misbehaves. You can

1. Close VS **(do not skip this step)**
2. Delete all 'bin' and 'obj' folders for all your projects.
3. Re-open VS and do a clean re-build on the solution.

This will either expose issues you may have missed or fix the red underlining.

Comment: I try it, but the same result, still red

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for you. Did you manually delete all the 'bin' and 'obj' folders from the file system? Doing just a clean does not work there. VS still caches something that breaks it.